# Base64 encoded string for simple sql injection

Tags: php, mysql, base64, sql-injection

**Except performance issue, is base64_encode() a "good" practice to prevent SQL injection?**

Of course not for all fields (columns) but just for one TEXT field (Example: in a contact form)

We know that characters returned by base64_encode() function are "safe" and not need even escape (correct me if I'm wrong) but I want to know if it's "safe" in every situation (charset encoding, or something similar ).

Simple practical example:

```
$dbc = new mysqli( DBHOSTNAME, DBUSERNAME, DBPASSWORD );

$name = preg_replace( "#[^A-Za-z0-9@_]#", "", $_POST[ "name" ] );

$phone = preg_replace( "#[^0-9 +]#", "", $_POST[ "phone" ] );

/*
Assuming this function check and sanitize a valid email
*/ 
$email = is_email( $_POST[ "email" ] );

$dbc->query( "INSERT INTO `testdb`.`testtable` 
( `name`, `email`,`phone`,`message` )
VALUES ( '$name', '$email', '$phone', '" . base64_encode( $_POST[ "message" ] ) . "' )" );
```

In other hand prepared statement:

```
$dbc = new mysqli( DBHOSTNAME, DBUSERNAME, DBPASSWORD );

$name = preg_replace( "#[^A-Za-z0-9@_]#", "", $_POST[ "name" ] );
$phone = preg_replace( "#[^0-9 +]#", "", $_POST[ "phone" ] );

/*
Assuming this function check and sanitize a valid email
*/ 
$email = is_email( $_POST[ "email" ] );

$stmt = $dbc->prepare( " INSERT INTO `testdb`.`testtable` 
( `name`, `email `phone`, `message` )
VALUES( '$name', '$email', '$phone', ? ) " );

$stmt->bind_param( 's', $_POST[ "message" ] );
$stmt->execute();
```

We have to deal with every kinds of hacking and injection techniques every day.

Logically PDO or mysqli (**with prepared statement**) are safe, but in my case the output (message) will converted anyway in base64 (Required by other parts of project) so why not converting before storing (well some extra space on database)

Comment: What's wrong with using a standard escaping mechanism, or bound params?

Comment: Actually I'm using prepared statement ( with mysqli ) and logically is correct, functional and save. Nothing wrong with it. Just curious about base64_encode() behavior in every situation.

Comment: Parameter binding in prepared statements is NOT just there to prevent SQL injection. Bind ALL your parameters, there really is no reason not to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Due the nature of base64_encode() function (make binary data survive transport through transport layers that are not 8-bit clean) you don't have to escape anything!

Characters returned are [0-9a-zA-Z/]

But I strongly suggest you to use prepared statement (with mysqli or PDO). Are a tiny bit slower but you will not change the **sanitizing logic** every time you deal with a table structure.

And also, not less important, maybe in the future you need to index the data on you table (Perhaps for search with LIKE or FULLSEARCH).

Your second example is correct (Bind ALL your parameters)

Answer (score 2):

The base64_encode function is not intended to escape strings, i.e. there is no warranty that a specific SQL dialect won't consider any base64-encoded character as a delimiter; you should always rely on dedicated escape functions.
However we don't know any SQL dialect that would consider a base64 character as a delimiter, so it would be safe anyway.

Comment: I have studied base64_encode() C source code ( /ect/standard/base64.c) and is completely **safe** (Using static base64_table array with chars in [A-Za-z0-9/] ).
Thats all I needed.

Comment: My concern was not about which characters are returned by base64_encode, but the way this characters may be interpreted by the sql engine. Let's say that a sql interpreter would use the slash (/) as a string delimiter, then a base64 encoded string could break the query. This is not sci-fi, for exemple in DB2 you can choose the string delimiter between the quotation mark (") and the apostrophe ('). As I said I don't know any sql language that use any character in [A-Za-z0-9/] as string delimiter, but this doesn't mean that there isn't (or wont be) one that would use them.