# Rich Text Editors Not Saving Certain Inputs from TextArea to MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, textarea, form-submit, wysiwyg

As part of building a content management app, I've run into a problem that I can't debug:

I've created a textarea field in a form that is modified by a rich text editor. I've tried a few editors: TinyMCE, SummerNote, and a few others, getting and gotten the same results both times.

The data submits fine in 90% of cases. In 10% of cases where I need to test a large block of text + formatting + images, when I submit a form it does all of the same actions as if it is submitting, but there is no actual DB write that happens, nothing is recorded or saved.

For example, I might copy/paste the main content of this page: https://knowledge.hubspot.com/articles/kcs_article/cms-blog/create-and-publish-a-blog-post as a 'bad' example of lorem ipsum that a user might input, and it won't save. But if I paste only the first step (from "Create a new Blog Post" to right below the first image), it saves it fine. Extremely long plain-text is saved fine.

The data is sanitized properly (I think):

```
      $itemname = $_POST['itemname'];
      $itemcomment = $_POST['textarea_content'];

      $query = "INSERT INTO `table`.`items` (`itemname`, `itemcomment`) VALUES ('$itemname', '$itemcomment');";

 mysql_query($query);
```

The data is saved in the DB under "itemcomment" as a `longtext` field encoding `utm8mb4_bin`.

Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't.

There are no error logs that I have found for this. The entire `post` seems to vanish into thin air with certain inputs.

Kind of at a loss at where to even begin debugging or what the issue could be. Perhaps some of the cruff formatting I'm pulling in is not properly cleaned?

Comment: I suggest more of an include problem than mysql.

Comment: the first error is showing `include(): Failed opening ..... in .../u/index.php on line 61, referer: .../insert_item.php`

Comment: @Tuckbros good catch, I guess I didn't read that properly. That seems to be a totally unrelated issue. I removed it that line of code (different function), tested again, and the error didn't show up but the bug described above did. A post with "ASDFASDF" goes through, but long rich-text formatting does not. No error recorded in logs.

Comment: out of using `mysql_query` which is deprecated you can try to secure your query using `mysql_real_escape_string` (as deprecated as `mysql_query`)on your variables. it can prevent from sql injection (maybe some chars of rich text are not safe for sql.

Comment: And as it seems your can embed some pictures and so on with your editors, you should think of either using something else than text in your db or encode your data with `base64_encode` but you will need to decode them for a later use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding your issue, you can go for different solutions

### keeping the db as is

```
  $itemname = base64_encode($_POST['itemname']);
  $itemcomment = base64_encode($_POST['textarea_content']);
```

but you will need to `base64_decode` after reading to get the original content.

### changing the datatype in the db

choose a `blob` or equivalent data type for your `itemcomment` column (I let you find how to write the insert)
You will certainly need to "prepare" the query.

Comment: This worked! I did both. Changing db column type to `blob` didn't address the problem on its own, but once I encoded/decoded w/ blog, it seemed to solve the issue. I'm going to assume that the copypasta text test I was using had some formatting that wasn't being escaped properly, and encoding/decoding more or less hides the issue.

Comment: As a corrollary, is base64 encoding a string before processing it in MySQL protect against SQL injection?

Comment: Not an expert, but I want to say yes, as the encoded string contains only alphanumeric values (with "+", "/" and "="). So no quotes, doublequotes, colon, semi-colon or I don't know what other char in the text string to be inserted could interpreted as a query. details there : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26791906/base64-encoded-string-for-simple-sql-injection